# Opening array in an API (puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to open a array from an API

tried using the code
const names_2 = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.mainDiv > Departure'), Departure => Departure.innerText));

But with no luck

Here is my input

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('http://xmlopen.rejseplanen.dk/bin/rest.exe/multiDepartureBoard?id1=8600646&format=json')

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let temperature = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerText;
temperature = JSON.parse(temperature);
    return {
        temperature
      }
  })

  console.log(result)


})()
```

This is my output

```
{
  temperature: {
    MultiDepartureBoard: {
      noNamespaceSchemaLocation: 'http://xmlopen.rejseplanen.dk/xml/rest/hafasRestMultiDepartureBoard.xsd',
      Departure: [Array]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you visiting a page that returns a JSON string? Can't you just get it and parse it?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but I'll look into it.
just tried removing '&format=json' from the url, but it did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here doesn't make sense. Simply request the data

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
rp.get({
    uri: 'http://xmlopen.rejseplanen.dk/bin/rest.exe/multiDepartureBoard?id1=8600646&format=json',
    json: true
})
    .then(res => res.MultiDepartureBoard.Departure)
    .map(e => console.log(e))
;
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted it to do!